# Issue with compiling bundled libs in Android Studio/Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I want to compile libs that are bundled in my project. And I run into 2 issues.

First of one that Cmake does not seems to detect/include that directory.

Second one is after bundled directory is detected/included instead of android toolchain a system's one is used to compile libs.

As workaround to 1st issue I added `if(ANDROID)` to add that directory so it can be included.

```
if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/CMakeLists.txt")
    message(STATUS "Using bundled libraries located at ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs")
    if(ANDROID)
        add_subdirectory(libs)
    else()
        include(libs/CMakeLists.txt)
    endif()
else()
```

So for me expected result should follow like this include libs/CMakeLists.txt and build libs using toolchain provided by NDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use non-ndk prebuilt library for your native component, then add those library details into CMake as mentioned below.

```
add_library( imported-lib
             SHARED
             IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
                       imported-lib

                       # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
                       PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

                       # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
                       imported-lib/src/${ANDROID_ABI}/libimported-lib.so )
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake#add-other-library

Comment: But what then if that non-ndk prebuilded lib does not exist yet ? I need to compile it somehow ? Here is snap of when I do enable BUNDLED_LIBS=ON in build.gradle.
https://pastebin.com/WxrXKCvt
This should use NDK toolchain instead of system one

Answer (score 0):

For building native library using cmake system.

1. define CMakeLists.txt in your module(local source code to be used for generating lib).

   add_library(xyz STATIC
           folder-name/xyz.cpp)

   ```
   target_include_directories(xyz PRIVATE
       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
   ```
2. define CMakeLists.txt in your android app module cpp folder.

   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

   /* using existing ndk lib , if you want you can remove this */

   ## build native_app_glue as a static lib.

   add_library(native_app_glue STATIC
        ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c)

   ## Import the CMakeLists.txt for the glm library

   add_subdirectory(glm)

   /* require if u r adding header files location */
   target_include_directories(game PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data
        ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue)

   ## add lib dependencies

   target_link_libraries(
        native_app_glue
        xyz
      )
3. define app module build.gradle

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 28

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId 'com.google.sample.tunnel'
       minSdkVersion 14
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode     1
       versionName    '1.0'

   }

   externalNativeBuild {
       cmake {
           version '3.10.2'
           path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt' // location of second(app module) CMakeLists.txt
       }
   }
   ```

   }
4. Also check CMake build commands to verify what all parameters are used during build.
   Check this file 
   app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86\cmake_build_command.txt

Comment: Thing is that project during compiling libs is using completly different aproach. Here is why. PS: I will do new post so you can see how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how it builds libcurl it does configure it 1st then compile using wrong toolchain. I did found something here https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems but it does export for 1 toolchain per build. Mine is using 2 abi's

```
ndk {
            // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
            // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
```

As you can see it's using ExternalProject_Add instead.

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
    # Build bundled cURL library
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------
    if(BUNDLED_CURL AND (BUILD_CLIENT OR BUILD_SERVER))

        ExternalProject_Add(
            bundled_curl
            SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/curl
            CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./configure --prefix=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/curl
            --enable-shared=no --enable-static=yes
            --enable-http --enable-ftp --disable-file
            --disable-ldap --disable-ldaps --disable-rtsp
            --enable-proxy --disable-dict --disable-telnet
            --disable-tftp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap
            --disable-smb --disable-smtp --disable-gopher
            --without-ssl --without-libssh2 --without-nghttp2
            --without-gssapi --with-zlib
            --disable-ares --enable-threaded-resolver
            --enable-ipv6 --enable-unix-sockets
            --without-libidn2 --disable-manual
            --disable-sspi --enable-libgcc
            --without-libmetalink --without-libpsl
            --without-librtmp ${CROSS_COMPILE32_FLAGS}
            PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/curl
            BUILD_COMMAND make
            INSTALL_COMMAND make install
            BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
        )

        set(CURL_BUNDLED_LIBRARY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/curl/lib/libcurl.a")
        set(CURL_BUNDLED_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/curl/include")
    endif()
```